# What's the point of -1 in recursion?

Tags: javascript, recursion

In this code block, am trying to understand the concept of recursion but, where I miss the whole point is this: `sum(arr, n) = sum(arr, n - 1) + arr[n - 1];`

I have this code block:

```
function sum(arr, n){

  if(n <= 0){
    return 0;

  } else {
    return sum(arr, n - 1) + arr[n - 1];
  }

}

console.log(sum([5, 4, 7, 9, 2, 6], 5);
```

I am trying to understand the expression: `sum(arr, n - 1) + arr[n - 1];`
is it that in: `sum(arr, n - 1)`, n is the (index - 1) OR (n - 1) is the length of array items it is going to add. Also, after this is done, what about the second expression arr[n - 1]. is [n- 1] an array element since it's in an array hence the "[]".

I apologize if any of this is silly or annoying but, i would really appreciate if someone could help point me in the right direction.

Comment: What steps have you taken to work out what this code is doing? Have you added breakpoints/console.logs to trace the output? What results do _you_ see?

Comment: The best way to understand how this works is to [learn how to use a debugger](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/) and step though it examining the variables as it goes.

Comment: Without the `-1` n will never be less than 0 and the function will never complete

Comment: yes i see 27 but am wondering how?

Comment: @DafeVictor — Andy meant *more* `console.log` statements so you could see what was happening each time the function was called and what the values of `arr` and `n` are each time … not just once at the very end.

Comment: Okay...am going to try that!

Comment: One (such as I) might argue that the *worst* way to understand recursion is with a debugger.

Comment: @ScottHunter Not even with the [Python Visualizer](https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html) (which also supports JS)?

Comment: why is `console.log(sum([5, 4, 7, 9, 2, 6], 5);` inside the sum function?

Comment: maybe you clean the code a bit and remove `else`, because of the return statement before. now you have two parts, the condition is the exit condition of the recursion and the later return statement is the part of recursion with moving the right part to stack and call the left part for getting a value. the result is a sum of index zero until (exclusive) given index.

Comment: Pen and paper, write it out.....

Comment: @ScottHunter because there is a thing called the edit button ... https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75889889/revisions

Answer (score 1):

Your function `sum(arr,n)` could be described as computing `arr[0]+...+arr[n-1]`.

Which is equivalent to `arr[0]+...+arr[n-2]+arr[n-1]`

Which is equivalent to `sum(arr,n-1) + arr[n-1]`

The only time this *doesn't* apply is when `n<=0`, in which case the sum is 0.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript arrays and other indexed variables are always **zero-based**, so the first element is index #0 whereas the length of the array is *last index + 1*.

See it here...

```
var A=['a','b','c','d']; // <--- the "n" here is 4 but the last item is index 3
```

There are four elements so the array lengthy is 4 but the last element's index number is 3 since the index goes.... [ 0, 1, 2, 3 ] !

Hence the **n-1** used so that the loop's counter won't run past the index of elements.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a recursive function you need to end the cycle somehow, otherwise the circle will continue and will consume all your memory, so paid attention to the if

```
if(n <= 0)

return 0
```

This condition wen n <= 0 end the cycle and return 0, so if you never make n <= 0 the cycle never end, then you have the implement a logic to do it sum(arr, n - 1), you then subtract -1 from n ultin it is 0 and the cycle end that means that line

Example

```
sum(arr, 4 - 1)
sum(arr, 3 - 1)
sum(arr, 2 - 1)
sum(arr, 1 - 1)

0
```